# Saving and printing information in C#.NET form

Tags: c#

I built a form using C#.NET. It has lot of text boxes. I am trying to save and print the information in the text boxes. I used the code:

```
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   if ((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
   {
       using (var writer = new StreamWriter(myStream))
       {
          writer.WriteLine("Information of Quote Number: ");
          writer.WriteLine(textbox1.Text);        
          writer.WriteLine("Total Cost: ");
          writer.WriteLine(textbox2.Text);
       }
    }    
    myStream.Close();
}
```

I am able to save it as a text file in four different lines and print it. I would like to have all of them in the same line. How can I write the code? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What about using `Write`instead of `WriteLine`?

Comment: While it is another writer, the concept of `Write` vs. `WriteLine` is evidently the same. Duplicate applies here.

Comment: @PatrickHofman that duplicate really applies. Sinatr proposed duplicate was another one

Comment: @Pikoh That was my duplicate which I was defending actually...

Comment: Ok, it seems deleted comments tricked me :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Write` method instead of `WriteLine`.  It doesn't include line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Write` instead of `WriteLine`.

Answer (score 0):

People are suggesting using `Write` instead of `WriteLine`.

Whilst, yes, they are correct. But only half correct.

You'll still want to use `WriteLine` when you want to break to a new line.

So, your new code will look like this:

```
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{

 if ((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
    {
     using (var writer = new StreamWriter(myStream))
           {
            writer.Write("Information of Quote Number: ");
            writer.WriteLine(textbox1.Text);        
            writer.Write("Total Cost: ");
            writer.WriteLine(textbox2.Text);
            }
     }    
            myStream.Close();
}
```

To get an output similar to

> Information of Quote Number: Some type of generated information.
>
> Total Cost: £3,500